# Call multiple JavaScript functions on onblur

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have to get a running total from four textboxes and have that total populate in two textbox controls. I was using `onblur` and that was working fine to display the total in one textbox. When I call this JavaScript function twice on the `onblur` event, I get an JavaScript error. Here is my JavaScript function.

```
function compute(clid, val1, val2, val3, val4) {
        var entry1 = Number(document.getElementById(val1).value);
        var entry2 = Number(document.getElementById(val2).value);
        var entry3 = Number(document.getElementById(val3).value);
        var entry4 = Number(document.getElementById(val4).value);
        var grandtotal = entry1 + entry2 + entry3 + entry4;
        document.getElementById(clid).innerHTML = grandtotal;
    }
```

And here is the codebehind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtdlscwinter.Attributes.Add("OnBlur", "compute('" + txtdlsctotal.ClientID + "','" + txtdlscwinter.ClientID + "','" + txtdlscspring.ClientID + "','" + txtdlscsummer.ClientID + "','" + txtdlscfall.ClientID + "'); compute('" + txtSpiffDLSC.ClientID + "','" + txtdlscwinter.ClientID + "','" + txtdlscspring.ClientID + "','" + txtdlscsummer.ClientID + "','" + txtdlscfall.ClientID + "');");
}
```

I am calling the same function twice but passing a different ClientID. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: when i click on the textbox to enter a value, i get unknown runtime error..

Comment: Its on this line: document.getElementById(clid).innerHTML = grandtotal;

Comment: What does the console show if you add `console.log( clid )` and `console.log( grandtotal )` before that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `value` rather than `innerHTML`.

Comment: If i set value, then i don't get an error but only one box is populated with the total. The second compute function works, not the first one in th onblur event.

Comment: Yup, it works. Sorry, my first total field was a Label instead of a TextBox. Changing to value works. Thanks!!